# Why my all xml sitemap contains 50000 links and not last extra pages?

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, sitemap

i am trying to build sitemap daily using php + mysqli (mariadb)

when i checked google for submitted sitemap, all i can see is every sitemap subbmitted has 50k urls in it. daily 3k-4k new Posts get added to the DB, so there should be last sitemap with extra URLs. What i am doing wrong ?

**sitemap generation logic**

```
<?php
    $subset_count = 50000 ;

    $total_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' " ;

    $total_count = mysqli_query ($conn, $total_count_query);
    $total_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_count);
    $total_count = $total_count['total_count'];
    $total_pages = ceil ($total_count / $subset_count);

    $current_page = 1;
    while($current_page <= $total_pages){
        $from = ($current_page * $subset_count) - $subset_count;

        //$get_mysql_data_query = " SELECT tpb_id, slug FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT $from , $subset_count"; // this is slow query

        $get_mysql_data_query = " SELECT tpb_id, slug FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' AND id >  $from ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 0 , $subset_count";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_mysql_data_query)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $link = 'https://example.com/post-id/'.$row['tpb_id'].'/'.$row['slug'];
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        $current_page++ ;
    }
```

**My table schema**

```
MariaDB [Db]> describe links;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tpb_id  | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | 0       |                |
| slug    | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| enabled | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

there are some `inactive records` in the table which i dont want them to be included in sitemaps, so i mark them as

```
enabled = '0'
```

**SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM links;**

```
+-------------+
| total_count |
+-------------+
|     4162840 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM links WHERE enabled = '1';**

```
+-------------+
| total_count |
+-------------+
|     4053924 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.91 sec)
```

I am trying to build sitemaps without making server unresponsive buy querying 4 mil records in a single query and then using array chunk to split the results.

---

**update 1:**

as suggested by Rick James,

> On the positive side, I was glad to see `id >  $from ORDER BY tpb_id
>   ASC LIMIT 0 , $subset_count` -- this makes fetching chunks efficient. 
>   Oh, wait; it is not efficient -- why `id` versus `tpb_id`?  Since
>   `tpb_id` is `UNIQUE`, get rid of `id` and promote `tpb_id` to be the
>   `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then use `tpb_id` in place of `id` in the `SELECT`.

i did changes and ran the sitemap script, still the last sitemap had exact 50k URLs.
on further inspection i noticed on sitemap page 82 , which is last sitemap page, i am getting last record whose tpb_id is `4188464` ,

if i do

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE tpb_id <= '4188464' AND enabled = '1'
```

then i get

```
334,564 rows
```

this means all sitemap pages included only `334,564` records from the database instead of `4mil+` records.

on further digging i found , sitemap pages `1-65` contains same `50k urls`.

It happened because the lowest `tpb_id` is `3211594`

---

**Update 2: undid changes as suggested by Rick James,**

i did some tests with 2 types of queries. (this one is slow)

**type 1: old mysql query**

```
MariaDB [db_name]> SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 5 ;
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id | tpb_id  | slug                                             | enabled |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 3211594 | High.Chaparall.S02E02.PDTV.XViD.SWEDiSH-HuBBaTiX |       1 |
|  2 | 3211609 | School.Of.Rock.PROPER.DVDRip.XviD-DMT            |       1 |
|  3 | 3211623 | Gyllene_Tider-Samtliga_Hits-SE-2004-WLM          |       1 |
|  4 | 3211625 | Oz_-_Season_One                                  |       1 |
|  5 | 3211626 | Prince_of_Persia_-_XBOX                          |       1 |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [db_name]> SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 5 , 5 ;
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
| id | tpb_id  | slug                                      | enabled |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
|  6 | 3211629 | Welcome.To.Mooseport.DVDSCR.XViD-DVL      |       1 |
|  7 | 3211639 | Top_Secret_Recipes_E-books                |       1 |
|  8 | 3211687 | Italian_Teens_Home_Video                  |       1 |
|  9 | 3211706 | Splinter_Cell_-_PandoraTomorrow_-DEViANCE |       1 |
| 10 | 3211770 | Revolution_OS                             |       1 |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

it is able to fetch records as expected.

**type 2:new fast query.**

```
MariaDB [db_name]>  SELECT * FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' AND tpb_id >  0 ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 5 ;
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id | tpb_id  | slug                                             | enabled |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 3211594 | High.Chaparall.S02E02.PDTV.XViD.SWEDiSH-HuBBaTiX |       1 |
|  2 | 3211609 | School.Of.Rock.PROPER.DVDRip.XviD-DMT            |       1 |
|  3 | 3211623 | Gyllene_Tider-Samtliga_Hits-SE-2004-WLM          |       1 |
|  4 | 3211625 | Oz_-_Season_One                                  |       1 |
|  5 | 3211626 | Prince_of_Persia_-_XBOX                          |       1 |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [db_name]>  SELECT * FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' AND tpb_id >  5 ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 5 ;
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id | tpb_id  | slug                                             | enabled |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 3211594 | High.Chaparall.S02E02.PDTV.XViD.SWEDiSH-HuBBaTiX |       1 |
|  2 | 3211609 | School.Of.Rock.PROPER.DVDRip.XviD-DMT            |       1 |
|  3 | 3211623 | Gyllene_Tider-Samtliga_Hits-SE-2004-WLM          |       1 |
|  4 | 3211625 | Oz_-_Season_One                                  |       1 |
|  5 | 3211626 | Prince_of_Persia_-_XBOX                          |       1 |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

above you can see type 2 is giving same output because of

```
tpb_id >  5
```

and tbp_id was not in incremental and had gaps in it.

---

**Conclusion:**
While using type 2 query which uses additional condition.
If table has `Auto Increment` field then we can use it for reference to get more records using `type 2` query which is fast.

so the final query which i was looking for (no, order by/ no, where enabled = 1 condition)

```
$get_mysql_data_query = " SELECT tpb_id, slug, enabled FROM links WHERE id > $from LIMIT 0 , $subset_count";
```

and then only using those having enabled = 1

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['enabled'] == 1){
        $link = 'https://example.com/post-id/'.$row['tpb_id'].'/'.$row['slug'];
    }
}
```

so now, it will use `id` for reference as its incremental and dont have gaps in it, and will scan all `4mil+` records, but only create sitemaps of only those which are enabled.

i have updated script as per above , and will update once the script completes the running.

---

update: the script is working great and making sitemaps of all pages, not all sitemap pages contains 50k because there are many enabled = 0 records, but thats fine as long as all urls are gets included in sitemaps.

here is the final script logic.

```
<?php
    $subset_count = 50000 ;

    $total_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM links" ;

    $total_count = mysqli_query ($conn, $total_count_query);
    $total_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_count);
    $total_count = $total_count['total_count'];
    $total_pages = ceil ($total_count / $subset_count);

    $current_page = 1;    
    while($current_page <= $total_pages){
        $from = ($current_page * $subset_count) - $subset_count;

        $get_mysql_data_query = " SELECT tpb_id, slug, enabled FROM links WHERE id > $from LIMIT 0 , $subset_count";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_mysql_data_query)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if($row['enabled'] == 1){
                    $link = 'https://example.com/post-id/'.$row['tpb_id'].'/'.$row['slug'];
                }
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        $current_page++ ;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [sitemap.org standards docs](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index):

> If you want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple Sitemap files.

That means with the amount of entries you have, you need to create more than a single sitemap file. Instead of that single sitemap file you need to create one index file that references as many sitemap files that you need to chunk all entries into 50 000 chunks.

Now keeping all rows in memory to create these files will perhaps crash your memory. So instead of using arrays for the result-set, you can make use of **Traversable**s which the database drivers in PHP (e.g. Mysqli or PDO) do support. These work on *each* entry and can stream from the database server, so this is much more memory friendly (and with normally only little runtime overhead - or at least as little as necessary to not run into memory problems).

For an example. Let's say the result from the database which represents the result-set is named

```
$result
```

and a **Traversable**. As you want to chunk it into 50 000 entries, you first warp it into a **NoRewind** iterator:

```
$chunkable = new NoRewindIterator($result);
```

This now allows to `foreach` over `$chunkable` multiple times w/o rewinding the result-set:

```
$chunkSize = 50000;
while ($chunkable->valid()) {
    foreach (new LimitIterator($chunkable, 0, $chunkSize) as $row) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here the **LimitIterator** is used to create the chunk of `$chunkSize` entries. The foreach will finish after a maximum of 50 000 entries then.

The `while` loop condition takes care that the overall iterator is still valid and if so, starts the next foreach loop.

The example is a bit verbose, it's perhaps better to wrap this in a **Generator** so it is easier to use:

```
function chunk(Traversable $traversable, int $size)
{
    $iterator = new IteratorIterator($traversable);
    $chunkable = new NoRewindIterator($iterator);
    # note: some Iterators need a rewind() to have valid() working, so
    #       in this example a "for" instead of a "while" loop is used.
    for ($iterator->rewind(); $chunkable->valid();) {
        $chunk = new LimitIterator($chunkable, 0, $size);
        yield $chunk;
    }
}


foreach (chunk($result, 50000) as $chunk) {
    # new sitemap

    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        # ...
    }
}
```

This is more memory friendly as you build one sitemap chunk after the other. For the index file you only need to keep track of the files you created.

Comment: so should i read all records from DB in single query and get the data in $result ?

Comment: Yes you can do so. This would also ensure that you can create the sitemap in one transaction. Technically you don't get all data at once, but you get the resultset which represents all data. That is a subtle difference, it allows you to not convert the whole resultset into an array though.

Answer (score 2):

Sanity check!

Who is going to look at 4 million links?  Or even 50,000 that exist on a single page?

What browser can load a page with 50,000 links in a reasonable length of time?

If you must build a bunch of pages with 4M links, put some structure in it -- alphabetical or categorized or some other logical grouping, not a blind N.

And make the size of each page much less than 50K items.  And make it at two levels deep.  Say, you had 3 levels; then each "page" could be a few hundred items; this is manageable for users *and* for PHP.

On the positive side, I was glad to see `id >  $from ORDER BY tpb_id ASC LIMIT 0 , $subset_count` -- this makes fetching chunks efficient.  Oh, wait; it is not efficient -- why `id` versus `tpb_id`?  Since `tpb_id` is `UNIQUE`, get rid of `id` and promote `tpb_id` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then use `tpb_id` in place of `id` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: i removed column id , and made tpb_id  as PRIMARY KEY, changed id to tpb_id in query, ran the script and still my last sitemap contains 50k urls., something is still not right.

Comment: is it because tpb_id is not incremental ? and there are gaps in it.

Comment: on page 82 i am getting last record whose tpb_id is 4188464 , if i do SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `tpb_id` <= '4188464' AND `enabled` = '1'  then i get 334,564 rows. something is weird.

Comment: If `$from` is now the last `tpb_id` on the previous page, you will get 50K per page.  Don't you mean ">=", not "<="?

Comment: on digging more, sitemap pages 1-65 contains same 50k links.because the lowest tpb_id is 3211594

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$perPage = 50000;
$identifier = 0;

while (false !== $identifier) {
    $sql = sprintf(
        "SELECT tpb_id FROM links WHERE enabled = '1' AND tpb_id > %d ORDER BY tpb_id ASC",
        $identifier
    );

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $identifiers = array_column($rows, 'tpb_id');

    $links = array_map(function ($id) {
        return sprintf(
            'https://example.com/post-id/%s'.
            $id
        );
    }, $identifiers);

    // now, write sitemap 

    $identifier = end($identifiers);
}
```

Comment: yes, but i have like 4 mil records and wouldnt it eat all the memory and  give me memory error ? thanks

Comment: Adjusted my suggestion!